# numberpicker decoration is over the number

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I'm using the pub [numberpicker](https://pub.dev/packages/numberpicker) and there is a parameter called decoration that I think is to do what i need, but the decoration (from a suposed container) is appearing over the number instead of below.

The code:

```
 NumberPicker(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: AppColors.morat,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                    ),
                    textStyle: AppTextStyle.lightXS.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                    selectedTextStyle: AppTextStyle.boldLarge.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                    itemWidth: 50,
                    itemHeight: 30,
                    zeroPad: true,
                    value: 12,
                    minValue: 0,
                    maxValue: 23,
                    step: 1,
                    onChanged: (value) {},
                  ),
```

The result:
[image]
the desired result (w/ photoshop):
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you like to try the stack widget?
Try placing the boxdecoration at the bottom of the stack and placing the numberpicker above it.

Comment: Yes i thought about it, but it needs to handle the exact position of the container to fit over the picker (with different screen sizes etc) and I thought it would be better solution if works from the original container of the pub.